# Type Error when passing data to web service in loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services

I have filled an array with data when the array has a certain number of records i use a web service to log the data to the database. However when i call the Web Service i am getting an error with the parameter passed:

**Error**

```
TypeError: citizens1[i] is undefined
data:{lat:citizens1[i].lat,
```

**Code**

```
//populates array 


citizens1.push({lat:marker[index].getPosition().lat(),lng:marker[index].getPosition().lng(),socialSecurityNumber:global_citizens[index].socialSecurityNumber});

         if(citizens1.length == 500){            
             console.log('500 records saved');          
             window.clearTimeout( timerHandle);

             for(var i = 1; i = citizens1.length ; i++){

                //array has data since the console.log works
                console.log(citizens1[i].lat +',' +citizens1[i].lng+','+citizens1[i].socialSecurityNumber); 
                 $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'logMovement.htm',
                        data:{lat:citizens1[i].lat,
                              lng:citizens1[i].lng,
                              socialSecurityNumber:citizens1[i].socialSecurityNumber},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success:function(data){

                            if (data == false){
                                console.log('error occured in logging data');
                            }

                        }

                    });          

             }

             citizens1 = [];
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements in an array go from `0` to `length-1`, so this line:

```
for(var i = 1; i = citizens1.length ; i++){   // NB = is an assignment, == is a comparison
```

should be

```
for(var i = 0; i < citizens1.length ; i++){
```

You're seeing an error when `i` is equal to `citizens1.length`, since that's beyond the end of the array.

Comment: That line in your code is definitely wrong, so if you've changed it and you are getting the same error your page might not have refreshed. Check the page source once you've loaded it. FWIW if you're going to make 500 calls to a server all at once you might as well not buffer them. You should assemble all your data into a JSON string and POST the whole lot at once.

Comment: i noticed when i made the 500 ajax calls i got 500 http 404 errors however the data was successfully logged to the database. Can you tell me how i can avoid these errors

Comment: The errors shouldn't be occurring. I see you're sending your AJAX Post to an HTM file - should that be PHP? If it's not something simple like that it will be to do with the server side code, and that's a different question.

Comment: i am using java and the data is getting logged successfully i dont know why i am getting this error for each request

Comment: The code might be failing not being executed to the end - that's why the server might throw the error in response, although the saving part might be successful already. Mike W is correct, need to see the server logs to be able to answer why.

Comment: @Pav Looking at my logs some data is being truncated maybe this could be causing the problem. Thanks